# Migrate Windows 7 guest VM to Generation 2?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, hyper-v, vhd, vhdx

Yes, I know that [officially](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v) Hyper-V Gen 2 VMs don't support Windows 7, but maybe there is some workaround or fix? Had anybody such experience?

I created new Gen 2 VM, converted my Win7 VHD to VHDx but without a luck. It simply doesn't recognize it.

Hyper-V host is Win10 Pro, if that matters.

Comment: If it's not supported maybe you should stop trying to make it work. Why do you want/need to do this?

Comment: Because Gen 1 doesn't support widescreen resolutions and I need it.

Comment: You can use RDP to a virtual machine instead of Hyper-V console. In that case any required resolution is possible.

Comment: @NetRunner, I know, but [messed icons after each RDP connection](https://superuser.com/questions/160421/desktop-icons-rearrange-after-using-remote-desktop-connection) drive me crazy :)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft released a tool for converting Hyper-V Gen 1 vms to Gen 2: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/mbr-to-gpt?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Like you said, Pre-Win10 OS is not officially supported but this tool will convert MBR to GPT and can be run from within Win10 (version 1703 or later) or booted into PE.

Comment: Where can I get it standalone?

Comment: You can boot into WinPE, more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive

Comment: `Windows 7, 8, or 8.1 are not officially supported`. I tried and it fails to read disk geometry.